# Joomla custom toolbar button message

Tags: joomla, message, toolbar

The standard admin toolbar buttons have the possibility that you can give them a message. For example: a "really delete" message or something...

```
JToolBarHelper::deleteList('Do you wanna really delete?', 'controller.delete');
```

Is that also possible for a custom button? In the documentation is no parameter for this. http://docs.joomla.org/JToolBarHelper/custom

Did Joomla have another solution? Show the user a message and after his confirmation... execute my code! Is that possible?

Sorry for my bad english :) 
thanks!

Comment: You could aslo take a look at the new joomla stack exchange site here :  http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 5):

Sure it is possible :)

Simply add to your component template view (for example:)

```
administrator/components/com_yourcomponent/views/your_view/tmpl/default.php
```

this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
    {
        if (task == 'customcontroller.delete')
        {
            if (confirm(Joomla.JText._('Do you really want to delete these items?'))) {
                Joomla.submitform(task);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Just change the task and edit the message and you should be ready to go

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to this url :
administrator/components/com_yourcomponent/views/your_view/tmpl/default.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
{
    if (task == 'customcontroller.delete')
    {
        if (confirm('Do you really want to delete these items?')== true)
        {
            Joomla.submitform(task);
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Joomla.submitform(task);
    }
}
</script>
```