# Add custom confirm message to standard joomla 3.0 admin toolbar button

Tags: javascript, php, joomla3.0

Add custom confirm message to standard Joomla 3.0 admin toolbar button.

I can get alert messages on delete when I don't select any check boxes on the detailed list.

I can get same on any button by set last parameter true in

```
JToolBarHelper::custom('userdetails.sendMail', 'mail.png', 'mail_f2.png', 'Send Mail', false);
```

I want to add a confirm message on the click event of this Button.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joomla custom toolbar button message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21682391/joomla-custom-toolbar-button-message)

Answer (score 3):

On view file (tpl/view file name).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Joomla.submitbutton = function(task)
    {
        if (task == 'userdetails.sendMail')
        {
            if (confirm(Joomla.JText._('Do you really want to send mails to selected users?'))) {
                Joomla.submitform(task);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addition to Suman Singh's answer, you may want to include the script in the document header, and also be able to translate the confirmation text. So, in your layout file, you can write:

```
$document = JFactory::getDocument();
$document->addScriptDeclaration('
  Joomla.submitbutton = function(task) {
    if (task == "userdetails.sendMail") {
      if (confirm(Joomla.JText._("COM_YOURCOMPONENT_USERDETAILS_SENDMAIL_CONFIRMATION_TEXT"))) {
        Joomla.submitform(task);
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
');
JText::script('COM_YOURCOMPONENT_USERDETAILS_SENDMAIL_CONFIRMATION_TEXT');
```

And of course in the `language/en-GB/en-GB.com_yourcomponent.ini` file:

```
COM_YOURCOMPONENT_USERDETAILS_SENDMAIL_CONFIRMATION_TEXT="Are you sure you want to send mails to the selected users?"
```